# How to return sum according to date range in django?

Tags: python, django

It'd be really nice if someone could help me with this. I've stuck here. I'm able to do this manually but how to do according to user input.

```
Payment.objects.filter(created_by=42, mode='cash', created_at__range=["2021-11-01", "2021-11-04"]).aggregate(Sum('amount'))
```

Here created_by and date_range I'm sending in url like this : `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/registration/?created_by=42&start_date=2021-06-06&end_date=2021-11-18` so the id created by and date_range will always change. And according to change the sum will return.

My Model :

```
class Payment(TimestampedModel):
    customer_visit = models.ForeignKey(
        CustomerVisit, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name="customer_payments"
    )
    mode = models.CharField(choices=PAYMENTCHOICES, max_length=25)
    amount = models.FloatField()
    ref_no = models.TextField(null=True)
    bank = models.ForeignKey(
        "BankDetails", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name="payment_bank"
    )
    is_settlement = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey("Employee", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True,related_name='payment_created_by')
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey("Employee", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True,related_name='payment_updated_by')
```

My View :

```
class UserWiseCollectionView(ListAPIView):
permission_classes = [
    IsAuthenticated,
]
pagination_class = CustomPagination
model = CustomerVisit
serializer_class = UserWiseCollectionSerializer
filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
filterset_fields = ['created_by']

def get_queryset(self):
    start_date = self.request.query_params.get("start_date")
    end_date = self.request.query_params.get("end_date")
    emp_id = self.request.query_params.get("emp_id")
    items = self.model.objects.all()
    if start_date and end_date:
        items = items.filter(
            created_at__range=[start_date, end_date]
        )
        if emp_id is not None:
            items = items.filter(phelebotomist_id = emp_id)
    return items
```

Comment: Please update the view part also!

Answer (score 0):

If requirement is to get all the rows created by specific employee within the specific date range, below code might work.

Requirement

```
Payment.objects.filter(created_by=42, mode='cash', created_at__range=["2021-11-01", "2021-11-04"]).aggregate(Sum('amount'))
```

View code

```
def get_queryset(self):
    start_date = self.request.query_params.get("start_date")
    end_date = self.request.query_params.get("end_date")
    emp_id = self.request.query_params.get("emp_id")
    employee = Employee.objects.get(pk=emp_id)
    payment_by_employee = employee.payment_created_by.all()
    if start_date and end_date:
        payment_by_employee = payment_by_employee.filter(
            created_at__range=[start_date, end_date], mode='cash'
        )
    
    payment_by_employee.aggregate(Sum('amount'))
    return payment_by_employee
```

If you want all the records related to specific employee within specific range in CustomerVisit table, you can make use of the related name that is provided to the field(foreign_key) pointing to an employee in customerVisit Table.

For example, if CustomerVisit model has "phelebotomist_id" foreign key that points to Employee Model, you can get all customerVisit records related to Employee Model by below queries

```
CustomerVisit(models.Model):
    phelebotomist_id = models.ForeignKey(Employee, related_name="employee_customer_visit")

emp = Employee.objects.get(pk=<emp_id>)
customer_visits_related_to_emp = emp.employee_customer_visit.all()
```

You can filter out further depending on the date range and any other fields.